# "Table is Empty" aún cuando hago el registro - SQLite en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-sqlite

hace poco estuve haciendo una base de datos bajo una guía de un video y me fue de maravilla, funciona perfectamente. Hace poco intenté hacer una aplicación mediante lo que aprendí en el video, seguí mis apuntes y demás y la aplicación se ejecuta pues el Android Studio no me señala ningún error.

El problema: Cuando ejecuto el método crea la tabla porque la veo en el "DataBase Inspector" pero la crea vacía y no se como solucionarlo:

Estoy iniciando en todo esto, disculpas desde ya si el error es muy obvio.

Este es el código de la clase java donde importo las librerías de SQLite en Android Studio

```
package com.example.iniciosesin2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class AdminSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable String name, @Nullable SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase DataBase) {
        DataBase.execSQL("create table datos(nombre int primary key, contraseña text)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Este es el código de la clase java donde ejecuto los métodos para registrar datos dentro de la base de datos:

```
package com.example.iniciosesin2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText nombre, pass1, pass2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name1);
        pass1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.contra3);
        pass2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.contra2);


    }

    //Para botón Registrarse

    public void Registrarse(View view){
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "Registro", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase DB = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        String name = nombre.getText().toString();
        String pas1 = pass1.getText().toString();
        String pas2 = pass2.getText().toString();

        if(!name.isEmpty() && !pas1.isEmpty() && !pas2.isEmpty()){
            if (pas1.equals(pas2)){
                ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();
                registro.put("nick", name);
                registro.put("contraseña", pas1);

                DB.insert("datos", "null", registro);
                DB.close();

                Toast.makeText(this, "El registro se completó", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent i = new Intent(this, Inicio.class);
                startActivity(i);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Las contraseñas no coinciden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No puede quedar ningún campo vacío", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    //Para el botón de salir

    public void Salir(View view){
        finish();
    }
}
```

Adicional:

Hay un intent para pasar de una activity a otra, cuando paso y uso el botón me cierra la app, *Creo que esto no está asociado al error de arriba, pero si de casualidad sabes me ayudarías mucho*

````
public class Inicio extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText nombre, contra;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);

        nombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name1);
        contra = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.contra3);


    }

    // Para el botón de Iniciar sesión

    public void Iniciar(View view){
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "Registro", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase DB = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        String name = nombre.getText().toString();
        String pass = contra.getText().toString();

        if(!name.isEmpty() && !pass.isEmpty()){
            Cursor fila = DB.rawQuery("select contraseña from datos where nombre =" + name, null);

            if(fila.getString(1).equals(name) && fila.getString(2).equals(pass)){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Hola" + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Usuario o contraseña incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Se deben llenar todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }

    //Método para salir
    public void Salir(View view){
        finish();
    }

    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente te comento que al insertar los datos deberías usar el mismo método [insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) para validar si se inserto correctamente la información de esta forma

```
           if(DB.insert("datos", "null", registro) == -1){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ocurrió un error en el registro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "El registro se completó", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
            DB.close();
```

ahora el problema que indicas,

> Cuando ejecuto el método crea la tabla porque la veo en el "DataBase
> Inspector" pero la crea vacía y no se como solucionarlo

me parece tienes es que la información se inserta correctamente, pero la consulta para obtener los datos es incorrecta, si lavariable `nombre` es una cadena tipo `String`, deberías de usar como contenedores las comillas sencillas (`'`) para indicar es un dato de este tipo, por ejemplo:

```
"select contraseña from datos where nombre = 'Cloudnine'"
```

Por lo tanto debes realizar este cambio:

```
 //*incorrecto Cursor fila = DB.rawQuery("select contraseña from datos where nombre =" + name, null);
  Cursor fila = DB.rawQuery("select contraseña from datos where nombre ='" + name + "'", null);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la solución, como necesitaba avanzar busqué en otros furos y en la versión de inglés de Stack Overflow, pero con tu explicación me queda muchísimo más claro.